# Time complexity of PHP's explode/implode

Tags: php, algorithm, time-complexity

I am interested if it is known what algorithms PHP uses for explode/implode functions, and what are their time complexities?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `O(N)`, I suppose. I don't see how you could do any better or any worse.

Comment: @KamilTomšík- This could be hugely important in a program that makes lots of calls to explode/implode on large data sets.  If the function is superlinear, then it would be a very bad idea to try using these functions in a large program and the OP would be better off reimplementing them to be faster.  If they're somehow sublinear, then it would be great to know because it would be worth rewriting code to try to use explode/implode more frequently.

Comment: @KamilTomšík I need to know the running time of the program using explode. as simple as that.

Answer (score 7):

In [`string.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c) you can see the algorithm. It starts at about [1021 line](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L1021)..

```
    if (p2 == NULL) {
    add_next_index_stringl(return_value, p1, Z_STRLEN_P(str), 1);
    } else {
    do {
        add_next_index_stringl(return_value, p1, p2 - p1, 1);
        p1 = p2 + Z_STRLEN_P(delim);
    } while ((p2 = php_memnstr(p1, Z_STRVAL_P(delim), Z_STRLEN_P(delim), endp)) != NULL &&
             --limit > 1);

    if (p1 <= endp)
        add_next_index_stringl(return_value, p1, endp-p1, 1);
    }
```

Its just a single loop So I'd call **it has `O(N)` complexity**. And check carefully the code. Its scanning the string and adding the result to `return_value`. So yes. **Its linear**.

Comment: One quick question - what is the complexity of `Z_STRLEN_P`?  If this isn't O(1), then the complexity would probably be more accurately O(mn), where n is the string length and m is the length of the delimiter.

Comment: @templatetypedef that is `O(1)`. Because `delim` is a zval and this macro is pointing to `(zval).value.str.val`

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:** For a single byte delimiter, `explode`’s time complexeity is in Ο(*N*‍); but for multiple byte delimiters, its time complexity is Ο(*N*‍<sup>2</sup>).

`implode` is clearly in Ο(*N*‍) as it simply glues the pieces together.

**Extended answer:** The [basic algorithm of `explode`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L1009) is to search for occurrences of *delimiter* in *string* and copy the enclosed substrings into a new array.

To find the positions of *delimiter* in *string*, it uses the [internal function `zend_memnstr`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.h#L249) (`php_memnstr` is just an alias for `zebd_memnstr`). For a single byte, it simply calls `memchr` that does a linear search (thus in Ο(*N*)).

But for *delimiter* values longer than one byte, it calls `memchr` to search for positions of the first byte of *delimiter* in *string*, tests if the last byte of *delimiter* is present at the expected position in *string*, and calls `memcmp` to also check the bytes in between. So it basically checks whether *delimiter* is contained in *string* for any possible position. This already sounds suspiciously like Ο(*N*‍<sup>2</sup>).

Now let’s have a look at the worst case for this algorithm where both the first and the last byte of the pattern fit but the second-last doesn’t, e.g.:

```
string:     aaaabaaaa
delimiter:  aaaaaa

aaaabaaaa
aaaaXa      (1+1+5)
 aaaX?a     (1+1+4)
  aaX??a    (1+1+3)
   aX???a   (1+1+2)
```

A `X` represents a mismatch in `memcmp` and `?` unknown bytes. The value in parentheses is the time complexity in uniform measure. This would sum up to

> Σ (2+*i*) for *i* from *M*-floor(*N*/2) to ceil(*N*/2)

or

> (*N*-‍*M*+1)·2 + Σ *i* - Σ *j* for *i* from 1 to ceil(*N*/2), *j* from 1 to *M*-floor(*N*/2)-1.

Since Σ *i* for *i* from 1 to *N* can be expressed by *N*·(*N*+1)/2 = (*N*<sup>2</sup>+*N*)/2, we can also write:

> (*N*-‍*M*+1)·2 + (ceil(*N*/2)<sup>2</sup>+ceil(*N*/2))/2 - ((*M*-floor(*N*/2)-1)<sup>2</sup>+(*M*-floor(*N*/2)-1))/2

For simplicity, let’s assume both *N* and *M* are always even, so we can omit the ‘ceil’s and ‘floor’s:

> (*N*-‍*M*+1)·2 + ((*N*/2+1)<sup>2</sup>+*N*/2+1)/2 - ((*M*-‍*N*/2-1)<sup>2</sup>+(*M*-‍*N*/2)-1)/2
>   = (*N*-‍*M*+1)·2 + *N*<sup>2</sup>/8+3·*N*/4+1 - ((*M*-‍*N*/2-1)<sup>2</sup>+(*M*-‍*N*/2)-1)/2

Furthermore, we can estimate the values up: *N*-‍*M* < *N* and *M*-‍*N*/2-1 < *N*. Thus we get:

> *N*·2 + *N*<sup>2</sup>/8+3·*N*/4+1 - (*N*<sup>2</sup>+*N*)/2
>   < *N*·2 + *N*<sup>2</sup>+4·*N* - *N*<sup>2</sup>+*N*

This proofs that `explode` with multiple byte delimiters is in Ο(*N*<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 3):

According to PHP sources on GitHub, it is linear. You can check `explode()` [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L1009).